# Windows Forms ListView always return Item.Checked = true

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm facing a problem in my ListView this always return (All True) regarding are Unchecked.

```c
foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewNotifications.Items)
{
    //I have 5 items all are true
    if (item.Checked == false) continue;
}

foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewNotifications.CheckedItems)
{
    //I have 5 items all are true here I get 5
}
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: how did you test it to arrive at the result that they are all Checked?

Comment: Hi @MongZhu I have 5 Items, then I clicked one by one to Unchecked

Comment: I was talking about the loop, how did you verify that inside the loop they are all checked ?

Comment: I Think I found the issue. I'm populating the ListView in a later moment, so if I Refresh() the ListView it assumes the original states. I'm finding a way to change on Click (Check State).

Comment: @MongZhu I just answer my question

Answer (score 0):

if you are populating a Windows.Forms.ListView in a previous moment, the Checked State is not updated, so I had to force it on the ItemClick

```cs
private void listViewNotifications_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.Checked == true)
    {
        e.Item.Checked = false;
        listViewNotifications.Update();
    }
    else
    {
        e.Item.Checked = true;
        listViewNotifications.Update();
    }
}
```

Can be any optimal solutions, but I don't have any problem to share mine even users mark question "No research effor", I didn't find nothing related.

If you find a better solution please share.